# Derivative of the current through a resistor in an RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, inductor, conductors

I have a circuit where I have to find di/dt at t=0+. At t=0+ the capacitor would have 0V across it and the inductor 0A through it. I was thinking of doing nodal analysis at the top and then differentiating or doing source transformation and mesh analysis then differentiating but whatever I do, I can't seem to find what di/dt should be.

[image: Circuit]

The solution from the solution manual is the following but I don't find it very intuitive:

[image: solution]

Comment: This isn't actually a question. I presume you mean to ask, how do you get the answer given in the manual? You should include your own best effort to show how far you get.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solutions manual has the better approach. At the instant the current source turns on, the capacitor acts like a short circuit, absorbing all the current. This causes the rate of change of the capacitor/resistor voltage to be determined entirely by the capacitor at \$t = 0^+\$.

Let's go through this in detail.

1. Initially, the capacitor is fully discharged (\$v_C = 0\$) and the inductor current is zero (\$i_L = 0\$).
2. After an instantaneous change in a circuit (like your current source turning on, a capacitor will act like a short circuit and an inductor will act like an open circuit. (Mathematically, we say that capacitor voltages and inductor currents can't change instantaneously.)
3. This means that at \$t = 0^+\$, \$v_C\$ and \$i_L\$ are still zero.
4. The capacitor and the resistor are in parallel, so they share the same voltage: \$v_R = v_C = 0\$. So at \$t = 0^+\$, by Ohm's law, no current flows through the resistor (\$i_R = 0\$).
5. Since \$i_R = 0\$ and \$i_L = 0\$, the only place the 4 amps from the current source can be going is into the capacitor.
6. Using the capacitor equation \$i = C \frac {dv}{dt}\$, we get:

$$\frac {dv_C}{dt} = \frac {4 \mathrm A} {0.25 \mathrm F} = 16 \mathrm{\frac V s}$$

7. Again, the capacitor and resistor share a voltage. So \${dv_R}/{dt} = {dv_C}/{dt}\$.
8. By Ohm's law:

$$\frac {di_R}{dt} = \frac 1 R \frac {dv_R}{dt} = \frac 1 {4 \Omega} \cdot 16 \mathrm {\frac V s} = 4 \mathrm{\frac A s}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, the current trough the resistor \$\text{R}=4\space\Omega\$ can be found using Laplace transform:

$$\text{I}_{\space4\space\Omega}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle4}{\displaystyle\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle4\left(\text{s}+6\right)}{\displaystyle4\left(4+\text{s}\left(\text{s}+6\right)\right)+4\left(\text{s}+6\right)}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Answer (score 0):

I transformed the circuit according to Laplace, then I calculated the Laplace transform of the current i(t) i.e. I(s), considering it as the partition current of the parallel composed of C and the series of L and R2. I0 is the amplitude of the generator current. i1(t) is the derivative of the current i(t) flowing in R1. v(t) is the voltage accross R1 :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for intuition. Not sure if the following helps there. But it's my shot at it, adding to the existing pile.

The current in the inductor+resistor branch must be 0 (assuming no initial current in the inductor) at \$t=0^+\$. So ignore it. At best, it's just there to serve as a distraction.

You know that \$I_\text{R}=\frac{V_\text{C}=V_\text{R}}{R}\$ and therefore that \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} I_\text{R}=\frac1{R}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(V_\text{C}=V_\text{R}\right)\$. But from the capacitor equation you also know that \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(V_\text{C}=V_\text{R}\right)=\frac{I_\text{C}}{C}\$.

So \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} I_\text{R}=\frac1{R}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(V_\text{C}=V_\text{R}\right)=\frac1{R}\cdot \frac{I_\text{C}}{C}=\frac{I_\text{C}}{R\,C}\$, where \$I_\text{C}\$ is taken at \$t=0^+\$ for this particular question.

Since \$V_\text{R}=V_\text{C}=0\:\text{V}\$ at \$t=0^+\$, then \$I_\text{R}=0\:\text{A}\$ and \$I_\text{C}=4\:\text{A}-I_\text{R}=4\:\text{A}\$.

So at \$t=0^+\$ then \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} I_\text{R}=\frac{I_\text{C}}{R\,C}=\frac{4\:\text{A}}{4\:\Omega\,\cdot\,\frac14\:\text{F}}=4\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{s}}\$.